# Add an array property to this Express.js model class

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

**What specific changes need to be made to the code below in order to successfully add a property that is an array of Strings to a JavaScript model object in an Express.js app?**  The `AppUser` code is placed in a new `appuser.js` file in the [`/app/models` directory of this GitHub link](https://github.com/scotch-io/node-todo/tree/master/app/models).

Here is the code for the `AppUser` class, including placeholders for the getters and setters for the array, which this OP asks how to write:

```
var method = AppUser.prototype;

function AppUser(name) {
    this._name = name;
}

method.getName = function() {
    return this._name;
};

//scopes
method.getScopes = function() {
    //return the array of scope string values
};
method.setScopes = function(scopes) {
    //set the new scopes array to be the scopes array for the AppUser instance
    //if the AppUser instance already has a scopes array, delete it first
};
method.addScope = function(scope) {
    //check to see if the value is already in the array
    //if not, then add new scope value to array
};
method.removeScope = function(scope) {
    //loop through array, and remove the value when it is found 
}

module.exports = AppUser;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use class in ES6 like this :

```
'use strict';
module.exports = class AppUser {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.scopes = [];
  }
  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
  getScopes() {
    return this.scopes;
  }
  addScope(scope){
    if (this.scopes.indexOf(scope) === -1) this.scopes.push(scope);
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to try if you want to improve your coding level. If that doesn't work, then post your code for help. Otherwise, we could think you just want to be your homework made

Comment: Don't forget 'use strict'; It works on my plateform with Express "version": "4.13.3". But that depends on how you use this class with express ...

Comment: fixed for ().  But "use strict" or 'use strict' is the same

Comment: fixed again for your release using indexof() test please

Comment: rather write this : newUser.getScopes()[i]

Comment: Good catch.  I do not have the rep to +1, but I am marking this as accepted.  Thank you for taking the time to examine this problem.

Comment: I am also researching how to enforce a unique `username` in this in-memory object.  If you have time to comment, I would appreciate any direction.  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275213/unique-primary-key-for-node-js-express-js-model-object

Comment: I will watch tomorow because it's late tonight at home in France.

Comment: I am researching Redis because it provides a scalable, multi-server approach to the other problem.  Thank you again for your help today.  Perhaps we will find each other again.