# Unique primary key for ES6 Node.js/Express.js Model Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**In a Node.js/Express.js app, what specific changes need to be made to the ES6 `AppUser` model object below so that the `name` primary key will always be unique?**

As context, the user is being authenticated by a separate OAuth2 authorization server, so this particular client Node.js/Express.js app will never store the user's information in a local database.  Therefore, the `AppUser` instance will exist only in memory, and will be a temporary holder of information about the user.  We cannot rely on a datastore like MongoDB to enforce the primary key because the user is not locally persisted.

Here is the code for the `appuser.js` file, which was added to [the `app/models` directory of this GitHub sample app](https://github.com/scotch-io/node-todo/tree/master/app/models) for testing purposes:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = class AppUser {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
  getSomeOther() {
    return this.someOther;
  }
  setSomeOther(other) {
    this.someOther = other;
  }
}
```

And here is an example of code that instantiates a new instance of `AppUser` elsewhere in the app:

```
var AppUser = require("./models/appuser.js");
...
var newUser = new AppUser(uname);
```

Comment: you will need to store the usernames somewhere. whether you update the model on the OAuth2 authorization server to enforce a unique key or store the usernames from your client app server. If you can't access the auth server then your best bet is to store each name used to a database and then query that db before authentication to verify it is unique.

Comment: @realseanp  The problem is that the Node.js user needs to temporarily store various information that should not be persisted anywhere, like tokens, etc. So I am imagining that your approach would require not only a `LocalUser` class with one single `username` primary key, but also some other class to store the `transient` data for the user that does not need to be persisted. This seems like a convoluted fix. In Java, there is a way to simply get all the instances of a class in memory, and access them individually by their primary keys. Is there a Node.js way to iterate instances of a class?

Comment: You can temporarily store data to a session using the express-session module https://github.com/expressjs/session. I would think the usernames would need to permanently persist and that would require the `LocalUser` model as you said. express-session stores sessions to memory by default, but they make note that that is not suitable for production and sessions should be stored to a database (which can be automatically done using one of the many session store modules that express-session references).

Comment: Then how does one handle `transient` properties that do not get persisted to the database?  In hibernate, there is `@transient` annotation that marks such properties to be in-memory-only.  Is there similar syntax to add to `transient` properties of ES^/Node.js/Express.js entities?

Comment: you could use the redis session store. https://github.com/tj/connect-redis . I haven't personally used it but have heard good things about redis. on the redis homepage it says Redis is an open source (BSD licensed), in-memory data structure store, used as database, cache and message broker. maybe that could work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to figure out the problem with vanillia. If you just want to check if name is unique during execution of the app, you could store names used for instanciation of the class in an array

```
'use strict';
var store = []
class AppUser {
  constructor(name) {
    if (store.indexOf(name) === -1) {
      this.name = name;
      store.push(name)
    }
    else {
      console.log("warning " + name + " already exists");
      return;
    }
  }
  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

var user1 = new AppUser("marco");
var user2 = new AppUser("raphaello");
var user3 = new AppUser("marco");
console.log(user2.getName());

run :
warning marco already exists
raphaello
```

Of course it's just an idea, and if this idea would deserve to be remained, throwing an exception would be better to make the instanciation abort than my return

Comment: How does the calling code check to see if `marco` exists, and then alter its behavior based on the answer?  e.g. `If marco` exists, then user=marco.  Else, user=new user(marco)`.  I have redis storing a user object, but I have the same problem of persisting the key for the user object in memory in Express/Node.  I am looking into having a JWT sent to the Angular client app and then letting that JWT help find the Redis key when the request comes back to the node.js/Express server.